# Changing listview item colors based on .database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, background

this is my first post in stackoverflow because this is the first thing i didn't find a clear answer.

I have an app that reads contacts from your android device and saves them in a sqlite database. what i want to do is change the background color of each listview row based on a .variable in the database.

More specifically, i want to change the color based on a value in the database which ranges from 1 to 3, 1 willing to be red, 2 green and 3 blue. I know how to change the color if each row once with a custom adapter like this

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      int colorPos = position % colors.length;
      view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
      View row = convertView;


      return view;
    }
```

}

but i cant find a way to read the name of the contact from the listview, retrieve the correct value from the database and change the color of  the row depending on the value retrieved from the database.

Any leads?

Comment: What is your database design? what have you done till now to retrieve data from database?

Comment: I have a class named databaser which is used to retrieve, save and manipulate the data in the database. My main activity creates an instance of databaser which is used to execute sql queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is example of changing the color of single row depend on condition .. this code will be inside of the getView method

```
    String value =  getItem(position);
    if (value.contentEquals("0")) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.yellow));
    } else if (value.contentEquals("1")) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.white));
    }else if (value.contentEquals("2")) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.red));
    }
```

Use getItem to get the object that you put in the adapter depend on the row position.. and while you only adding a single string in each row we define a string to get the value of the specific row to check and change the color depend of the value

Comment: Yes i understand that, any idea how the condition can be an sqlite database read?

Comment: hmm i did not really understand what your problem .. but did you create a method to retrieve the data form sqlite database?

Comment: u can get the value of each row from the object and that is the list of string.. see the updated answer

Comment: This is the accepted answer, thank you, but i noticed that this way to do it is not very effective! I have to change the way i am handling this! thank you anyway